# Azure devops - ArchiveFiles@2 task - archive files from remote repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am preparing azure devops and terraform automation. I have prepared pipeline, and one of my task is presented below:

```
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: "terraform file archive"
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: zip
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip
      replaceExistingArchive: true
      verbose: true
```

Mentioned pipeline task prepares archive.zip file, archive.zip file contains only files from Azure devops repo where my pipeline .yaml file is stored (only files from local repo). I need to archive files from another Azure Devop repo and add them to archive.zip. Is there any possibility to do this using Azure devops tasks?

Comment: Hi, have you got a chance to check the suggestion below? If the answer works for you, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ArchiveFiles@2` task will archive everything from `rootFolderOrFile`.
As mentioned by you, only the triggered repo files are available for copying.

But when you [check out more then one repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline, you might achieve your goal.

For example:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: otherRepo
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

steps:
  - checkout: otherRepo
  - checkout: self 

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: "terraform file archive"
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: zip
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip
      replaceExistingArchive: true
      verbose: true
```

Two things are important here:

1. Declare your other repo(s) in the resource part
2. Since multiple repos are present, don't forget to check out the triggering repo as well with: `checkout: self`

Comment: Hi promicro, looks fine, I read the MS doc You suggested, only one question, what should be the format of the `checkout` block? I have only one organization and two projects, I need to pull files from second project repo,  I am talking about this block `- checkout: "git://Second_project_name/second_project_repo_name"`.

Comment: The inline checkout can also be used, but I'm used to use the approach as mentioned above, although this is not necessary according to the docs

Comment: Still getting error message `The Git repository with name or identifier second_repo_name does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.` and `fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/Organization_name/Project_name/_git/second_module_name/' not found `

Comment: And repos within the same organization? If that works, than look at the permissions of the build service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-build-service-account-permissions

Comment: I meant repos within the same project.

Answer (score 1):

To use the repository from `AnotherProject` in the same Azure DevOps organization in your YAML pipeline, you can take reference to the sample below to [checkout multiple repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) with either `repository resource definition` or `inline syntax`.

```
trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

# Repository resource definition
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: AnotherProjectRepo_01
    type: git
    name: AnotherProject/REPO_01

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: AnotherProjectRepo_01

# Inline syntax checkout
- checkout: git://AnotherProject/REPO_02

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: Show Build.SourcesDirectory

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    verbose: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

When we have multiple `checkout` steps in the agent job, the source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of `s` in `Agent.BuildDirectory`;

If a `path` is not specified for a checkout step, you can archive the files under the `build.SourceDirectory` which will contain all the checked out repositories.

[image: Show Build.SourcesDirectory]

[image: Archive.zip]

For a YAML pipeline to checkout repository from `AnotherProject`, please make sure the `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` is disabled in the `Project Settings` where the pipeline locates. Thus, the pipeline will be running as `Project Collection Build Service (AzureDevOpsOrgName)` to checkout the repository from `AnotherProject`, therefore please also pay attention to the security settings of the source repository in `AnotherProject`.

[image: Project Settings]

[image: Repo Security]